# uninitialized constant Improvingoutcomes (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to add gzip compression to my Heroku app. After searching I found that it should be as easy as modifying the config.ru:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::Deflater
run Improvingoutcomes::Application
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/manuel/my_app/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Improvingoutcomes (NameError)
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/manuel/my_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/manuel/my_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a case-sensitivity/capitalization issue. What does application.rb look like, specifically the `module Improvingoutcomes` bit. My guess is something like `module ImprovingOutcomes`.